# Getting an instance of an event aggregator each time I have to subscribe to an event?

Tags: c#, prism

I have three events to which a WPF app must subscribe.  Is it necessary to get an instance of an event aggregator each time I have to subscribe to an event?

Here is how I am doing it now:

```
                IEventAggregator eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
                eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<IncidentInfoReadyEvent>().Subscribe(OnIncidentInfoReady);

                eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<IncidentInfoReadyEvent2>().Subscribe(OnIncidentInfoReady2);

                eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<ArrestInfoReadyEvent>().Subscribe(OnArrestInfoReady);
```

Can I do it this way:

```
                IEventAggregator eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
                eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<IncidentInfoReadyEvent>().Subscribe(OnIncidentInfoReady);
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<IncidentInfoReadyEvent2>().Subscribe(OnIncidentInfoReady2);
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<ArrestInfoReadyEvent>().Subscribe(OnArrestInfoReady);
```

Comment: _"Can I do it this way"_ -- What happened when you tried it that way? Why are you asking us, when you could much more easily just try it out and see? Also, why did you tag this question as a [tag:wpf] question? It does not appear to have anything to do with WPF per se. `EventAggregator` is a Prism thing, not WPF. Also, why do you call `new EventAggregator()`, when all you're going to do next is discard that object?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `ServiceLocator` at all to begin with.

Comment: Well, if I'm going to get this much flak for asking a question,  I'll just try it and see if it goes or blows.  Thanks so much for the critique.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do dependency injection in your class.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggreator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEventOne>().Subscribe(() => DoSomething());
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEventTwo>().Subscribe(() => DoSomething());
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEventThree>().Subscribe(() => DoSomething());
    }
}
```

There is no need to take a new instance each time. But you should  register  logger in container as singleton.